# Matching the rownames/colnames order between two matrices

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, function, matrix

I have a named vector like: `Rs = c(L2DA.L2DF= .64, L2DA.L2G= 0.55,...)` (*see below*). I also have a corresponding `length(Rs) x length(Rs)` matrix called `V_matrix` whose rownames/colnames match the order of `Rs` (*see below*).

*So, the position of the elements of `Rs` and `V_matrix` match (they both have the same rownames/colnames).*

Now, imagine I convert `Rs` to a correlation matrix like `R_matrix` (*see below*) where `R_matrix`'s rownames/colnames are gotten by separating the `names(Rs)` by `"."` and *then* ***reordering them alphabetically***, like this:

```
row.col <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(Rs), "[^[:alnum:]]+"))
nam <- sort(unique(c(row.col)))
corr <- matrix(NA, length(nam), length(nam), dimnames=list(nam, nam))
diag(corr) <- 1
corr[rbind(row.col, row.col[, 2:1])] <- Rs
(R_matrix = corr)
```

**Question:** I wonder how to reorder the elements in `V_matrix` to match any reordering of the elements of `Rs` that happened when `Rs` were converted to `R_matrix`?

```
Rs <- c(L2DA.L2DF = 0.64, L2DA.L2G = 0.55, L2DA.L2L = 0.42, L2DA.L2M = 0.56, 
L2DA.L2P = 0.57, L2DA.L2V = 0.48, L2DF.L2G = 0.37, L2DF.L2L = 0.24, 
L2DF.L2M = 0.29, L2DF.L2P = 0.48, L2DF.L2V = 0.35, L2G.L2L = 0.48, 
L2G.L2M = 0.57, L2G.L2P = 0.29, L2M.L2L = 0.51, L2P.L2L = 0.33, 
L2P.L2M = 0.48, L2R.L2DA = 0.58, L2R.L2DF = 0.46, L2R.L2G = 0.52, 
L2R.L2L = 0.56, L2R.L2M = 0.49, L2R.L2P = 0.47, L2R.L2V = 0.51, 
L2V.L2G = 0.53, L2V.L2L = 0.52, L2V.L2M = 0.53, L2V.L2P = 0.42)

R_matrix <- structure(c(1, 0.64, 0.55, 0.42, 0.56, 0.57, 0.58, 0.48, 0.64, 
1, 0.37, 0.24, 0.29, 0.48, 0.46, 0.35, 0.55, 0.37, 1, 0.48, 0.57, 
0.29, 0.52, 0.53, 0.42, 0.24, 0.48, 1, 0.51, 0.33, 0.56, 0.52, 
0.56, 0.29, 0.57, 0.51, 1, 0.48, 0.49, 0.53, 0.57, 0.48, 0.29, 
0.33, 0.48, 1, 0.47, 0.42, 0.58, 0.46, 0.52, 0.56, 0.49, 0.47, 
1, 0.51, 0.48, 0.35, 0.53, 0.52, 0.53, 0.42, 0.51, 1), dim = c(8L, 
8L), dimnames = list(c("L2DA", "L2DF", "L2G", "L2L", "L2M", "L2P", 
"L2R", "L2V"), c("L2DA", "L2DF", "L2G", "L2L", "L2M", "L2P", 
"L2R", "L2V")))

V_matrix <- structure(c(0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.167, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.083, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.053, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.037, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.25, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.091, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.083, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.029, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.056, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.03, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.043, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.071, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.043, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.016, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.034, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.059, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.083, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.067), dim = c(28L, 
28L), dimnames = list(c("L2DA.L2DF", "L2DA.L2G", "L2DA.L2L", 
"L2DA.L2M", "L2DA.L2P", "L2DA.L2V", "L2DF.L2G", "L2DF.L2L", "L2DF.L2M", 
"L2DF.L2P", "L2DF.L2V", "L2G.L2L", "L2G.L2M", "L2G.L2P", "L2M.L2L", 
"L2P.L2L", "L2P.L2M", "L2R.L2DA", "L2R.L2DF", "L2R.L2G", "L2R.L2L", 
"L2R.L2M", "L2R.L2P", "L2R.L2V", "L2V.L2G", "L2V.L2L", "L2V.L2M", 
"L2V.L2P"), c("L2DA.L2DF", "L2DA.L2G", "L2DA.L2L", "L2DA.L2M", 
"L2DA.L2P", "L2DA.L2V", "L2DF.L2G", "L2DF.L2L", "L2DF.L2M", "L2DF.L2P", 
"L2DF.L2V", "L2G.L2L", "L2G.L2M", "L2G.L2P", "L2M.L2L", "L2P.L2L", 
"L2P.L2M", "L2R.L2DA", "L2R.L2DF", "L2R.L2G", "L2R.L2L", "L2R.L2M", 
"L2R.L2P", "L2R.L2V", "L2V.L2G", "L2V.L2L", "L2V.L2M", "L2V.L2P")))
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure what order you are after. In your example data, is any reordering needed, or is `V_matrix` ordered correctly. How would you like to reorder `V_matrix` if `names(Rs)` was e.g. `B.C, A.C, B.A`?

Comment: @RobertHacken, if you notice, `names(Rs)` and `rownames(V_matrix)` are currently fully aligned so `V_matrix`'s elements have a one-on-one correspondence to the `Rs` elements. But after we convert `Rs` into a `R_matrix`, we change the order of the elements of `Rs`. This reordering is done based on the sorting the `names(Rs)` broken up at the `"."`. So, the ordering is based on `L2DA, L2R,...` rather than `L2DA.L2DF, L2DA.L2G`. But is it possible to change the ordering of `R_matrix` the same a `V_matrix`?

Comment: I don't think I follow and maybe what you ask for is not possible. You can't base the ordering of `R_matrix` on `L2DA.L2DF, L2DA.L2G, ...`, i.e. on two things at the same time (that is, the part before and after the `.`).

Comment: @RobertHacken, this has to do with how a vector is turned into a matrix. For example, the first column of `R_matrix` excluding the diagonal elements reads: `[L2DF, L2DA]`, `[L2G, L2DA]`, `[L2L, L2DA]`, `[L2M, L2DA]`, `[L2P, L2DA]`, **`[L2R2, L2DA]`**, `[L2V, L2DA]`. BUT now look at the `V_matrix` and you'll notice `L2R2.L2DA` (which is the same as `L2DA.L2R2`) doesn't appear after `[L2P, L2DA]` as is the case in `R_matrix`. So, in `V_matrix`, `L2R2.L2DA` has to be moved after `L2P.L2DA` (which is the same as `L2DA.L2P`) rowwise and columnwise to match that in `R_matrix`. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```r
# matrix containing column and row name combinations
col.row <- outer(colnames(R_matrix), rownames(R_matrix), FUN=paste, sep='.')

# modified rownames of V_matrix where the part before '.' is lexicographically
#   larger than the second part -- the way it is in the lower triangle of col.row
v.names <- strsplit(rownames(V_matrix), '\\.') |>
  lapply(sort, decreasing=T) |>
  sapply(paste, collapse='.')

# reorder V_matrix according to R_matrix's lower triangle
ord <- match(col.row[lower.tri(R_matrix)], v.names)
V_matrix.ord <- V_matrix[ord, ord]

rownames(V_matrix.ord)
#  [1] "L2DA.L2DF" "L2DA.L2G"  "L2DA.L2L"  "L2DA.L2M"  "L2DA.L2P"  "L2R.L2DA" 
#  [7] "L2DA.L2V"  "L2DF.L2G"  "L2DF.L2L"  "L2DF.L2M"  "L2DF.L2P"  "L2R.L2DF" 
# [13] "L2DF.L2V"  "L2G.L2L"   "L2G.L2M"   "L2G.L2P"   "L2R.L2G"   "L2V.L2G"  
# [19] "L2M.L2L"   "L2P.L2L"   "L2R.L2L"   "L2V.L2L"   "L2P.L2M"   "L2R.L2M"  
# [25] "L2V.L2M"   "L2R.L2P"   "L2V.L2P"   "L2R.L2V"
```

Comment: This seems great +1, but we don't want to replace any of the `V_matrix` elements with those from `R_matrix` or add any elements to `V_matrix` . Rather, we just want to re-order the `V_matrix` elements that are out of sync with the similarly named elements in the `R_matrix`. . . .

Comment: . . . . For example, the first column of `R_matrix` excluding the diagonal elements reads: `[L2DF, L2DA]`, `[L2G, L2DA]`, `[L2L, L2DA]`, `[L2M, L2DA]`, `[L2P, L2DA]`, ***`[L2R2,L2DA]`***, `[L2V, L2DA]`. BUT now look at the `V_matrix` and you'll notice `L2R2.L2DA` (which is the same as `L2DA.L2R2`) doesn't appear after `[L2P, L2DA]` as is the case in `R_matrix`. So, in `V_matrix`, `L2R2.L2DA` element has to be moved after `L2P.L2DA`  element (which is the same as `L2DA.L2P`) both rowwise and columnwise to match that in `R_matrix`. Is this possible?

Comment: @SimonHarmel Oh, sorry, somehow I convinced myself that `V_matrix` is basically `diag(Rs)` which it isn't. Does my modified answer now do what you need?

Comment: Yes, I think so! Thanks!